# toggle nav on and off

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's in this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gme06L8/11), I am trying to toggle the nav on and off, but doesn't seem to be working. It's seems to close the nav bar once clicked, then do nothing else. I'm pretty new to working with jQuery. Can anyone tell me how I can correct this, and also I need the nav not to even show before the menu button is clicked. Thanks!

```
    $(function() {
      var showMenu = false;
      $('#menuButton').click(function() {
        if (showMenu) {
          $('#menu').css({'display':'none'});
          showMenu = false;
          return;
        }
        $('#menu').css({'display':'block'});
        showMenu = true;
      });
    });
```

Comment: The main fault is -- your `#menuButton` is being called twice one a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gme06L8/23/)

I have change selector to `checkbox` ie `#spinner-form2` instead of `#menuButton`

Comment: Thank you very much friend. Now how can i combat the issue of the nav showing before the button is pressed?

Comment: here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0gme06L8/26/. I have added `nav{ display:none;}` in `CSS`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you want to toggle, so do so:

```
$("#menuButton").click(function() {
    $("#menu").toggle();
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hi can you put this in a working fiddle? I understand the toggle function but still doesn't seem to work.